# MySQL query multiple count() and a sum()

Tags: mysql

I trying to create a query that pulls 2 columns from a MySQL table. One column (User) is the user, the other column (caseType) has three potential values. The query counts the amount of times the user has selected the values and gives a total. I would like to calculate the sum() of 3 columns created with count(), creating a TOTAL column.

I started with a query to pull the three columns based on the User.

```
select User,
       count(case when caseType = 'FAXCOM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as FAXCOM,
       count(case when caseType = 'IMA' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as IMA,
       count(case when caseType = 'DREAM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as DREAM 
from Records group by User;
```

| User | FAXCOM | IMA | DREAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| admin1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| chris | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| chunker | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| user1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Then I created a query to get the totals of the 3 columns.

```
Select User, SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) as TOTAL from 
       (select User,
       count(case when caseType = 'FAXCOM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as FAXCOM,
       count(case when caseType = 'IMA' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as IMA,
       count(case when caseType = 'DREAM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as DREAM
       from Records group by User ) 
as Total group by User;
```

| User | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| admin1 | 1 |
| chris | 2 |
| chunker | 10 |
| user1 | 0 |

Then I tried to combine the 2 queries. And this is where I'm running into a problem. It's adding up ALL the records instead of per row. I figure it's just the order I have it in, but I can't seem to get it right. How do I write the query so it adds up per row, instead of all the rows?

```
select User,
       count(case when caseType = 'FAXCOM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as FAXCOM,
       count(case when caseType = 'IMA' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as IMA,
       count(case when caseType = 'DREAM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as DREAM,
(Select SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) as TOTAL from 
       (select User,
       count(case when caseType = 'FAXCOM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as FAXCOM,
       count(case when caseType = 'IMA' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as IMA,
       count(case when caseType = 'DREAM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as DREAM
       from Records) as Total group by User)
from Records group by User;
```

| User | FAXCOM | IMA | DREAM | Select SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) as TOTAL from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| admin1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 13 (should be 1) |
| chris | 1 | 0 | 1 | 13 (should be 2) |
| chunker | 1 | 3 | 6 | 13 (should be 10) |
| user1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 (should be 0) |

Comment: You have already calculated FAXCOM and another 2 values in the subquery - what is the reason for to calculate them again in outer query?

Comment: Just add columns to the outer query: `Select User, FAXCOM, IMA, DREAM, SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) as TOTAL`. And you don't need another `group by` in the outer query.

Comment: I calculate them again because if I don't, and I just put FAXCOM, IMA, DREAM in the outer query, I receive the error that FAXCOM, IMA, or DREAM are Unknown columns.

Comment: D'oh! I kept using a 2nd select in front of the SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) whenever I copied and pasted the queries. Tunnel vision got me. Jared was correct with his comments as is the answer below given by Clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select User, FAXCOM, IMA, DREAM, SUM(FAXCOM+IMA+DREAM) as TOTAL FROM(
    Select User,
       count(case when caseType = 'FAXCOM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as FAXCOM,
       count(case when caseType = 'IMA' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as IMA,
       count(case when caseType = 'DREAM' and Status='CLOSED' then 0 end) as DREAM 
    from Records GROUP BY User) AS auxTable
GROUP BY User;
```